# Constructing a libKML driver in R

Tags: r, kml

I am working with KML files in R and have been struggling because the KML driver only seems to show two of the data's attributes "Name" and "Description". I know for a fact there are plenty more since I've opened the files in ArcGIS.

From my research I have the suspicion that working with the libKML driver could fix my problem but can't seem to find a way to construct it (install it?). 
Does anyone know how I can do this or if there is a better way to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'driver'? A package? Which package have you tried?

Comment: A driver is a class that instantiates the program you're working with. I am trying to work with the rgdal and sf libraries. To view your drivers you can do sf::st_drivers(), where all available drivers can be seen (and libKML is missing!), at least for my version of the rgdal package.